# How to increase the blob size in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, size, blob

As I'm using Delphi to upload the image and SQL Server database to store the image.

Comment: Please be more specific in your question.

Comment: http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Answer (score 2):

Use `VARBINARY(MAX)` [field type](http://www.developer.com/net/asp/article.php/3761486/Working-with-Binary-Large-Objects-BLOBs-Using-SQL-Server-and-ADONET.htm)  it can be up to 2GB size (MSSQL 2005 and greater).